# PRAW bot only parsing one subreddit when wanted to parse multiple

Tags: python, bots, praw

I'm writing a bot that parses specific subreddits for titles of posts that contain specific characters. As you can see below, in the `r.subreddit()` method, I've passed `'nba'`, but also want the bot to parse `'nbadiscussion'`, `'warriors'`, and `'NYKnicks'`.

How come it's only grabbing the top posts from `/r/nba`? Thanks!

```
def run_bot():
    sub = r.subreddit('nba+nbadiscussion+warriors+NYKnicks')
    print("Grabbing subreddit")
    subs = sub.top('year', limit=5)
    print("Grabbing posts in sub")
    for posts in subs:
        article_url = posts.url
        post_title = posts.title
        print(post_title)
        print(article_url)

        string1 = post_title
        durantRegex = re.compile(r'[KevinDurantKnicks]')
        x = durantRegex.search("Kevin Durant Knicks", string1)  

 run_bot()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want 5 results from each sub youd be better off using a for loop over a list of subs.

```
subs_to_search = ['nba', 'nbadiscussion', 'warriors', 'NYKnicks']

for sub_name in subs_to_search:
    sub = r.subreddit(sub_name)
    subs = sub.top('year', limit=5)

    for posts in subs:
        article_url = posts.url
        post_title = posts.title
        print(post_title)
        print(article_url)
```

So on and so forth, so you're doing an action for each sub. It'll get 5 from each, do what you need it to do, then move to the next subreddit Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `limit=5` you've specified in `subs = sub.top('year', limit=5)` is limiting your result set from the combined subreddits to just five results altogether.

Try upping the `limit` parameter or removing it altogether to see results from the other subreddits as well.

Comment: This is not the case. The top 100+ posts in the listing OP is searching through are all from /r/nba because /r/nba is more popular and so has posts with higher scores.

Answer (score 0):

> How come it's only grabbing the top posts from r/nba?

Because of the **relative popularity** of each of these subreddits.

If we look at the web version of the query you're making, it will become obvious:

https://reddit.com/r/nba+nbadiscussion+warriors+NYKnicks/top?t=year

/r/nba is vastly more popular than the other subreddits, so its top posts (sorted by score) overshadow the posts from the other subreddits. For reference, here are the top posts of the year for the other subreddits:

- [/r/nbadiscussion](https://reddit.com/r/nbadiscussion/top?t=year)
- [/r/warriors](https://reddit.com/r/warriors/top?t=year)
- [/r/NYKnicks](https://reddit.com/r/NYKnicks/top?t=year)

At the time of this post, the highest-scoring post in any of these subreddits is [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/warriors/comments/8yvy4y/this_is_james_a_ugandan_who_works_where_im/) from /r/warriors, with 5171 points. That's a far cry from the 63k points that the [top post in /r/nba](https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/bgqlf3/dame_hits_the_game_winner_at_the_buzzer_tnt/) has.

---

Ari Victor suggests a good way of getting posts from each sub; namely, iterating over the list of subs and individually getting their top posts.

Note that the behavior described above does not happen with hot listings. With hot listings, you can expect an about even distribution of all subreddits involved, because post scores are weighted by community size. So, another possible solution is as follows:

```
def run_bot():
    print("Grabbing subreddit")
    subs = r.subreddit('nba+nbadiscussion+warriors+NYKnicks')
    print("Grabbing posts in sub")
    for posts in subs.hot(limit=5):
        article_url = posts.url
        post_title = posts.title
        print(post_title)
        print(article_url)

run_bot()
```

Note that this solution gets hot posts rather than top posts. Whether you want hot posts or top posts depends on your specific application.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I had lacked understanding of how the praw API wrapper works.